# Forms to Send Attachment in Email

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I'm new here, but after surfing through many pages, I've came up with a form that actually works and sends an attachment to my email. However, when an attachment is not attached at the time the form is filled out, I get this instead of the Thank You Page.

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/advem/public_html/careers.php on line 21
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/advem/public_html/careers.php:21) in /home/advem/public_html/careers.php on line 61

However, the email still gets sent to me when an attachment is not used.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        //Deal with the email
        $to = 'email@testdesign.net';
        $subject = 'New Proof Request';
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

        $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
        $sku = $_POST['sku'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

        //Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

        $headers = "From: email@testdesign.net\r\nReply-To: $visitor_email";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$name
$sku
$message
$phone

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        //done. redirect to thank-you page.
        header('Location: thank-you-proof-request');
        
        // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

    }
?>
```

I've also tried the answer at the following link, but never have luck there either.

[PHP - sending email with attachment does not show message content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818263/php-sending-email-with-attachment-does-not-show-message-content)

Comment: Just add a check to see if `$_FILES` contains anything before using the `file_get_contents` function. As for the header already sent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Qirel.....can you tell me how to write that and where to put it? Everything I have so far is merely copying and pasting from different questions on Stackoverflow. I'm afraid I'll mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code on line 21 to:

```
    $attachment = '';
    $filename = '';
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] != 4 && file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ 
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    }
```

And on line 51 :

```
    if(!empty($filename)){
        --_1_$boundary
        Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
        Content-Disposition: attachment 

        $attachment
        --_1_$boundary--";
    }
```

I suggest you to use a library for sending email like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), it has a lot of stuff that can be used and its easy to used.